# `in` operator doesn't work as expected when checking whether a pandas Series contains a given value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following series zar which contain timestamps:

```
In [743]: zar
Out[743]: 
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-03-21
2   2019-04-19
3   2019-04-22
4   2019-04-27
5   2019-05-01
6   2019-06-17
7   2019-08-09
8   2019-09-24
9   2019-12-16
Name: zar, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [744]: zar[5]
Out[744]: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00')

In [745]: j
Out[745]: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00')

In [746]: j in zar.values
Out[746]: False
```

since both contains timestamps why is the result False?
I want to return True when matching timestamps in a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j in zar` will compare `j` with each element of `zar`'s *index*.

For example,

```
0 in zar
# True

0 in zar.index
# True
```

This is also consistent with the behaviour of DataFrames, for which `in` by default does a membership test on columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a' in df
# True

'd' in df
# False
```

You'll need `Series.eq` (`==` operator) or `Series.isin`, along with `Series.any`.

```
(zar == j).any()
```

---

**Details**
`zar == j` returns a Series of bools:

```
(zar == j)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: zar, dtype: bool
```

You then call `any` which returns True if any of the rows are True. If you want the index of the True value, use `np.flatnonzero`:

```
np.flatnonzero(zar == j)
# array([5])
```

Comment: Thanks. if i convert everything to datetime instead of timestamps then
`j in zar.values` returns `True` without having to use `isin` or `any()`.
Just wondering why that was the case.

Comment: @deep_butter As long as you use the equality operator or the `isin`, it should work.